# Remove formatting from US phone number and their extension number

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

HI need help get phone number and there extension using either replace or regex

```
phone
(123) 455-6789 --> 1234556789
(123) 577-2145 ext81245 --> 1235772145

extension
(123) 455-6789 --> 
(123) 577-2145 ext81245 --> 81245
```

`"(123) 455-6789" -replace "[()\s\s-]+|Ext\S+", ""
"(123) 455-6789 Ext 2445" -replace "[()\s\s-]+|Ext\S+", ""`

This solves phone number but not extension.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?  Have you tried to solve this problem yourself yet?

Comment: You should probably write "North American phone number" in your question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```
^\((\d{3})\)\s*(\d{3})-(\d{4})(?: ext(\d{5}))?$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of the line respectively.
- **`\((\d{3})\)`** - Represents first capturing group matching the digits inside `()`.
- **`\s*`** - Matches a white-space character zero or more times.
- **`(\d{3})-`** - Represents second capturing group capturing exactly 3 digits followed by a `-`.
- **`(\d{4})`** - Represents third capturing group matching the digits exactly 4 times.
- **`(?: ext(\d{5}))?`** -

  - **`(?:`** Represents a non capturing group
  - **`ext`** - Followed by a space and literal `ext`.
  - **`(\d{5})`** - Represents digits exactly 5 times.
  - **`)`** - Closing of the non-captured group.
  - **`?`** - Represents the quantifier making the whole non-captured group optional.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the sample demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/11HFUh/1)

**Powershell Commands:**

```
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop> $input_path='C:\Path\To\MyDesktop\InputFile.txt'
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop> $output_path='C:\Path\To\MyDesktop\outFile.txt'
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop> $regex='^\((\d{3})\)\s*(\d{3})-(\d{4})(?: ext(\d{5}))?$'
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop> select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { "Phone Number: $($_.matches.groups[1])$($_.matches.groups[2])$($_.matches.groups[3])             Extension: $($_.matches.groups[4])" } > $output_path
```

**Sample Result:**
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

After you've replaced all characters, you could split the result to get two numbers

**Applied to your example**

```
@(
'(123) 455-6789'
 , '(123) 577-2145 ext81245'
) | % {
    $elements = $_ -replace '[()\s\s-]+' -split 'ext' 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        phone = $elements[0]
        extension = $elements[1]
    }
}
```

**returns**

```
phone      extension
------     ---------
1234556789          
1235772145 81245
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this pattern. It will match phone numbers with **and** without parentheses, spaces and hyphens.

```
((?:\(?)(\d{3})(?:\)?\s?)(\d{3})(?:-?)(\d{4}))
```

Answer (score 0):

So alternatively, you could use two replace functions in a single go. Say your original data sits in `File1.txt` and you want to output to `File2.txt` then you could use:

[image]

```
$content = Get-Content -Path 'C:\File1.txt'
$newContent = $content -replace '[^\d\n]', '' -replace '^(.{10})(.*)', 'Phone: $1   Extention: $2'
$newContent | Set-Content -Path 'C:\File2.txt'
```

[image]